# Make CSS sprite animation work

Tags: css, animation, sprite, css-animations

Im new to css animation, so I got this sequence movements picture online and want to make it walks. I follow a tutorial but it doesn't work in this case. I'm trying to make it moves. I don't know how to properly do that so I start with the first row of image. Its dimensions are 832x228.

and this is CSS code:

```css
.sprite {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOPXb.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  animation: walker 1s steps(8) infinite;
}
@keyframes walker {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 832px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path but the `background-position` is wrong within the keyframes. Sprite images should move from the right to the left in order to produce a moving animation and so the background position should go from `0 0` to `-832px 0`.

```css
.sprite {
  width: 114px;
  height: 114px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOPXb.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  animation: walker 1s steps(8) infinite;
  /* image size is 832x228, so height is set as half of it */
}
@keyframes walker {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -832px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='sprite'></div>
```

---

As mentioned in Robert C's answer, this will still not get the second row of images to show up. This is because the Y part of `background-position` doesn't change within the keyframes. The below snippet kindly contributed by Mishko Vladimir is one way to get them to display but problem is that if the no. of steps is increased to 16 (so as to show all sprites) then the animation doesn't work properly anymore.

Also, there will be a blink at the point where Y position changes. ***So, my recommendation would be to put all 16 sprites in the same row instead of two.***

```css
.sprite {
  width: 114px;
  height: 114px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOPXb.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  animation: walker 1s steps(8) infinite;
  /*832x228*/
}
@keyframes walker {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: -832px 0px;
  }
  51% {
    background-position: 0 -114px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -832px -114px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='sprite'></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome @pexichdu. Like Robert mentioned in his answer, if you want the bottom row of images also to come into the animation then it would be tough. It is better to put them in the same row.

Comment: @MishkoVladimir: I am going to accept your change because you've made a couple of very valid edits. However, I am going to remove the loop part for the second row because it doesn't quite work as expected. For example, there is only 8 steps so we will not get to see all 16 sprites. Next, we will see a blink where the image goes from the last sprite in the top row to the first one in the bottom row. Please don't mistake. I appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the wrong `background-position`, it should be `-832px` rather than `832px`.  Note that with the above image you're also only going to get the top 8 frames, you'll need to edit the file to get the bottom 8 for a longer transition.

You may also want to adjust the time in your `animation` down to a fraction (I had a smoother walk with 0.9), and you'll want to shrink your `width` and `height` down to around `115px` to avoid seeing some of the other frames.